# How to create a video plugin for Rich Text Editor

Tags: plugins, aem

I need to create Video plugin for Rich Text Editor(RTE) in CQ5. I referred the following url “http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html” . There is no plugin ID for video.

I want to create new icon in RTE as edit and findreplce plugin. When we click on video icon, One dialog has to open with some input values to give video path and video heading.

Is there any video plugin available for RTE? Could anyone please guide me to create video plugin for RTE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no OOTB plugin available for video, but you may create a video plugin by extending CQ.form.rte.plugins.Plugin. For reference see FindReplacePlugin.js which is in /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/rte/plugins/FindReplacePlugin.js. You can add a custom icon image to your plugin.

Comment: I have added "image" plugin ID under rtePlugins. But I am unable to see image icon in Rich Text Editor(RTE). I can see spellcheck and mistools If I add 'spellcheck, mistools' plugin IDs. Pls tell me What could be the problem?

Comment: kindly add your code. RTE has a OOTB image plugin id are you trying to change its image ? Not sure what are you doing and why you need that. Ideally you need to create a custom plugin ID for video by extending CQ.form.rte.plugins.Plugin. Also keep in mind to go through  the code of initializeUI function of FindReplacePlugin.js there in the line tbGenerator.addElement("findreplace", plg.Plugin.SORT_EDIT + 5, this.findUI,
                    100);  allows to display find replace rte plugin at 5th pos from SORT_EDIT. You may need customization based on the position you want it to be displayed.